# undefined method `id2nkame' for :trace_output:Symbol (NoMethodError) in rake (10.0.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I ran the rake, returned an error:

```
/Users/reg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/ostruct.rb:166:in `method_missing': 
undefined method `id2nkame' for :trace_output:Symbol (NoMethodError)
```

I had no idea about this error, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you got `ostruct.rb` changed, but line 166 is `mname = mid.id2name` and hasn't changed for 15 years, so just change `id2nkame` to `id2name` in the file you got in the error message and all should be good.

Comment: Yes, maybe something wrong happened to my ruby-1.9.3-p194,
I just upgrade this ruby-1.9.3-p194 to the ruby-1.9.3-head, everything is OK now.